# Asp content not filling bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

In my asp.net master page I have a navbar which spans two columns using bootstrap's grid system and another div spanning 10 columns which contains my `asp:ContentPlaceHolder`. An iframe is placed into the content placeholder from another page. The iframe's width is set to 100%. The problem is that the iframe never fills out the rest of the width of the page. See code below.

In my Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Technology.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <style>
         .container, .body-content, .row,.col-xs-2, .col-xs-10{
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
         }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%">
    <form runat="server" style="height: 100%">
        <div class="container body-content" style="height: 100%; width:100%">
           <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
              <div class="col-xs-2" >
                 <ul class="nav nav-stacked affix" id="sideNavBar"  
                    style=" background-color:rgb(207,205,225); color:rgb(33,40,89); 
                      border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin;">
                       <!--List items on navbar...-->
                 </ul>
              </div>
              <div id="contentContainer" class="col-xs-10" 
                  style="float:right; margin:0px; padding:0px; height:100%;">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <footer>
                  <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - MCF Intranet</p>                 
                </footer>

              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the page providing the content:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
   AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeBehind="TechPages.aspx.cs"  
      Inherits="Technology.TechPages" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
    <div style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> 
            <iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" src="Pages/Word_and_DM_Word2007.htm" runat="server" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border-width: 0px; height:100%; width:100%; ">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have set margin and padding to 0 for all rows and columns and for the container in which they are placed so I can't understand why the 10 column div won't take up the remaining width of the page. Can anyone help resolve this?

Comment: Kill your inline styles for one and the overrides for padding/margin. I'd put the form inside of the container and row and remove widths. `container-fluid` is 100% width. `pull-right` is the utility for floating right. Getting a proper Bootstrap setup would probably help as a good starting point. It's hard to debug when that's borked.

Comment: Yeah sorry I know that's incredibly messy I was just throwing in `height`and `width` properties everywhere to try and fix it. Changing my `body-content` container to a `container fluid` solved the problem completely so do you want to write that as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks

Comment: I've made my comment an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `container-fluid` which is 100% width and remove padding/margin and other overrides. `pull-right` is the utility for floating right. Using Bootstrap utilities from the get-go helps solve debugging issues. Looks like the other inline styles and overrides were conflicting with Bootstrap.